# Hey is it possible to call one serializer class insider another in drf? Without having any foreign key relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class AuthorSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
            model =  Author
            fields = "__all__"

class BookSerializer(ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
            model =  Book
            fields = "__all__"
```

I want to get data of AuthorSerializer in BookSerializer.
Is it Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [serailizerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class BookSerializer(ModelSerializer):
      author = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

      def get_author(self, obj):
           """ code to perform query """
           author = Author.objects.all()
           return AuthorSerializer(author, many=True).data

      class Meta:
            model =  Book
            fields = "__all__"
```

The return statement inside `get_author` function explained:

Returning the `author` as such returns the query set (thats not the way of serializer), so we pass the data in to `AuthorSerializer` to make it JSON object. The first argument passing (ie. `author`) is the query set, and secondly `many=True` is to say that we are passing multiple objects (in the query set). Lastly `.data` returns the data serialized.

Comment: Object of type `Author` is not JSON serializable. Getting error like this

Comment: Hey can you explain me the working of this?
I dont understand this part
```
           author = Author.objects.all()
           return AuthorSerializer(author, many=True).data
```

Comment: First let me know if this is working, then i can explain the answer for you?

Comment: it is working. That's why I have asked you to please explain it

Comment: @Sins97 explanation added to the answer. Make sure to mark this answer as accepted, it will also help others to know the correct answer.

Comment: what if i dont want all the fields of `AuthorSerializer`. How to do that. I cannot change fields in AuthorSerializer because it needs to be called in others too